# C# sum of intergers in array using foreach

Tags: c, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach, sum

Please help. Got stuck with this code tried different things but cannot make it work properly. I have a "foreach" loop, where technically it must sum all the integers in the 2D array, however, the answers calculated isn't what it is expected to be. What am i doing wrong? thank you thank you.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        const int ROWS = 2;
        const int COLS = 2;
        const int MAX = 5;

        string input;
        int[,] numbers = new int[ROWS, COLS];


        do
        {
            int total = 0;
            double avg = 0;
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int rows = 0; rows < ROWS; ++rows)
            {
                for (int cols = 0; cols < COLS; ++cols)
                {
                    numbers[rows, cols] = rand.Next(1, MAX);
                }
                {
                    for (int cols = 0; cols < COLS; ++cols)
                        Console.Write(" {0, 3}", numbers[rows, cols]);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

    foreach (int cell in numbers)
                {
                    total += cell;
                } 

                avg = total / 4.0;

            } Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0:0,0}   Average: {1:f}", total, avg);

            Console.Write("\nWould you like to generate a new table? Type yes or no... ");
            input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (input == "no")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("End of program. Press any key to exit. Goodbye.");
            }
        }

        while (input == "yes");






        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

So i found the logic error. I moved the "foreach" loop outside of "for" loop and it fixed an error. Thank you for your time and support. Here's the working code:
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        const int ROWS = 2;
        const int COLS = 2;
        const int MAX = 5;

        string input;
        int[,] numbers = new int[ROWS, COLS];


        do
        {
            int total = 0;
            double avg = 0;
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int rows = 0; rows < ROWS; ++rows)
            {
                for (int cols = 0; cols < COLS; ++cols)
                {
                    numbers[rows, cols] = rand.Next(1, MAX);
                }
                {
                    for (int cols = 0; cols < COLS; ++cols)
                        Console.Write(" {0, 3}", numbers[rows, cols]);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            } 


                foreach (int cell in numbers)
                {
                    total += cell;
                }

                avg = total / 4.0;
            Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0:0,0}   Average: {1:f}", total, avg);

            Console.Write("\nWould you like to generate a new table? Type yes or no... ");
            input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (input == "no")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("End of program. Press any key to exit. Goodbye.");
            }
        }

        while (input == "yes");






        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think that your foreach is redundant here:

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < ROWS; ++rows)
{
    for (int cols = 0; cols < COLS; ++cols)
    {
        numbers[rows, cols] = rand.Next(1, MAX);
        total += numbers[rows, cols]; // Sum in the same loop
    }

    for (int cols = 0; cols < COLS; ++cols)
        Console.Write(" {0, 3}", numbers[rows, cols]);
    Console.WriteLine();

    avg = total / 4.0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @QtRoS that your cycle was redundant - you summed up values of all cells twice (for each row).

But I think there is one more error in code (in @QtRoS's answer as well).
If you want to calculate average of all grid cells, you must do this after cycle on rows.

This way:

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < ROWS; ++rows)
{
    for (int cols = 0; cols < COLS; ++cols)
    {
        numbers[rows, cols] = rand.Next(1, MAX);
        total += numbers[rows, cols]; // Sum in the same loop
    }

    for (int cols = 0; cols < COLS; ++cols)
        Console.Write(" {0, 3}", numbers[rows, cols]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

avg = total / 4.0;
```